# how to remove rows based on different crateria in one run

Tags: r

I have a data looks like this

```
df<- structure(list(V2 = c(15L, 20L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 40L, 0L, 1538100000L, 
0L), V3 = c(142480000L, 20L, 0L, 0L, 100L, 0L, 0L, 1444000000L, 
100L), V4 = c(170130000L, 0L, 0L, 1577400000L, 0L, 0L, 1577400000L, 
1577400000L, 20L), V5 = c(176030000L, 0L, 0L, 176030000L, 0L, 
20431000L, 0L, 1449700000L, 0L)), .Names = c("V2", "V3", "V4", 
"V5"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("A", "B", "C", "D", 
"F", "G", "H", "I", "J"))

#          V2         V3         V4         V5
#A         15  142480000  170130000  176030000
#B         20         20          0          0
#C          0          0          0          0
#D          0          0 1577400000  176030000
#F          0        100          0          0
#G         40          0          0   20431000
#H          0          0 1577400000          0
#I 1538100000 1444000000 1577400000 1449700000
#J          0        100         20          0
```

What I want to do is to remove those rows that have zero which can be done like this

```
df[rowSums(df)>0, ]
```

Now I want to remove those rows that have only one value and the rest are zero 
Then I want to remove those columns that half of the values are zeros (either right or left)

expected output should look like this

```
#          V2         V3         V4         V5
#A         15  142480000  170130000  176030000
#B         20         20          0          0
#D          0          0 1577400000  176030000
#I 1538100000 1444000000 1577400000 1449700000
```

> row named C is removed because all members were zero
>
> F was removed because only one value was there and the rest were zeros
>
> G was removed because (lets say if we have 4 columns , we should have
>   values for 2 either the first 2 or the last 2) and G had two values
>   but was not close
>
> H was removed because had only one value
>
> J was removed because did not have two values either at two first
>   column or two last columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using temporary variables

```
## logical array indicating non-zero elements
nz <- array(df != 0, c(dim(df) / c(1, 2), 2))

rowSums(nz) > 1                         # conditions 1 & 2
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE

## rows with no zeros in the left half
apply(nz[, , 1], 1, all)
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE

## rows with no zeros in the right half
apply(nz[, , 2], 1, all)
#[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE

## rows with no zeros in either the left or the right half
rowSums(apply(nz, c(1, 3), all)) > 0    # condition 3
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

I think the first two conditions are redundant.

```
## rows that satisfy all conditions simultaneously
ind <- rowSums(nz) > 1 & rowSums(apply(nz, c(1, 3), all)) > 0

which(ind)
#[1] 1 2 4 8

df[ind, ]
#          V2         V3         V4         V5
#A         15  142480000  170130000  176030000
#B         20         20          0          0
#D          0          0 1577400000  176030000
#I 1538100000 1444000000 1577400000 1449700000
```

Comment: it is very straight !!! thanks , why the first two conditions are redundant ? one more question what if the number of columns were 6 instead 4 and I wanted to have them in 3 columns light and left? what if I want only that are in left numbers not both left and right ? can you please edit the answer ? by the way I liked you answer already

Comment: @nik As I see it, the third condition implies that the first two conditions are true, therefore it shouldn't be necessary to check for all the three conditions.

Comment: @nik The solution should work with any data frame with any number of columns, although I have only tested it with 4 columns.

Comment: @nik I've added two examples that show how to check for zeros in the left and right halves separately

Comment: if I have 6 columns and I want to have instead 2 ,3 I should only change the first line ? nz <- array(df != 0, c(dim(df) / c(1, 2), 2))

Comment: @nik No, it wouldn't work. This solution requires the same number of columns to the left and to the right.

Comment: 6 columns means 3 in left and 3 in right now? so how can I do that for it? in the above example we had 4 means 2 right and 2 left . so if I have 6 (3 right and 3 left) then what should I do?

Comment: @nik You don't need to change anything. The line `nz <- array(df != 0, c(dim(df) / c(1, 2), 2))` divides the data-frame by columns in two halves. It works independently of the number of columns, as long as the number of columns is divisible by 2. So 4, 6, 8 ... columns will work.

Comment: so whatever column I have as long as it is divided by 2, I don't need to change anything and all the rules will be applied on the data?

Answer (score 2):

I.   First attempt

```
  df[rowSums(df) > 0 & rowSums(df==0) != ncol(df)-1 & df[,1] != 0 & df[,2] !=0 | df[,3] !=0 & df[,4] !=0,]
  #           V2         V3         V4         V5
  # A         15  142480000  170130000  176030000
  # B         20         20          0          0
  # D          0          0 1577400000  176030000
  # I 1538100000 1444000000 1577400000 1449700000
```

II.  To know index values of rows removed, put the opposite condition in `which()` function

```
   which(rowSums(df) <= 0)
   # C 
   # 3 

   which(rowSums(df==0) == ncol(df)-1)
   # F H 
   # 5 7
```

Comment: Note: its not general formula for the last condition, i.e. removing rows not having consecutive non zero values on half left or half right. Its specific to this one. the first two conditions are general.

Comment: can you make it less complicated ? even if it is not in one run, it is ok! also how can I find which rows are removed (my mean their index) . please update your answer with extending it , keep what you have wrote so that I can go through it

Comment: @nik: Please can you edit the third part of your question, i.e. half left and half right, you have mentioned you need to remove columns instead of rows and also that the consecutive values of half left and half right should be zero. How ever in output you are checking non-zero values if they are consecutive in left half or left half.

Comment: I liked your answer, but i think the question should not be change

Comment: The statement `Then I want to remove those columns that half of the values are zeros (either right or left)` if u see in output there r rows with half zeros on either left or right & ur other statement `G was removed because (lets say if we have 4 columns , we should have values for 2 either the first 2 or the last 2) and G had two values but was not close` &  `J was removed because did not have two values either at two first column or two last columns`. R u checking `non-zero` or `zero` values for first half and second half of columns?

Comment: Ur statements & expected output doesn't match for 3rd condition.

Comment: I will check it out , now I am not able to, I will definitely do it and update you